# Why is extension with wildcard as generic parameter not allowed in java?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, wildcard

I was wondering why it is not allowed to use wildcards in java super-class as a template parameter. I was confrontet with this issue, when I implemented a generic interface multiple times with different template-parameters like this:

```
interface A<THIS extends A<THIS>> {...}
interface B<THIS extends B<THIS>> {...}
interface C extends A<C> {...}
interface D extends B<D>, C {...}
```

In this case `A` is implemented two times with `C` and `D` resulting in an error.

But in this special case, I dont care about the exact type of `A` and `B`, when they are extended, so it would be cool to use `?` as parameter like this:

```
interface A<THIS extends A<THIS>> {...}
interface B<THIS extends B<THIS>> {...}
interface C extends A<?> {...}
interface D extends B<?>, C {...}
```

**edit**: And neither `A` nor `A<?>` are a viable subsdetude for `A<THIS extends A<THIS>>` when extending it.

However, what actually worked is to use raw-types. The behavior is exactly what I expected from wildcards. And it's typeconform, too.

```
interface A<THIS extends A<THIS>> {
    THIS foo();
}
interface B<THIS extends B<THIS>> {
    @Overrid THIS foo();
}
interface C extends A {
    @Overrid C foo();
}
interface D extends B, C {
    @Overrid D foo();
}
```

Of cause there are warnings about using raw-types, but that's okay compared to the error before. Where is the difference using wildcards then? Obviously you can not set specific parameter to wildcards like `T<?,X>`. But for any type `T<P1,...,Pn>` the rawtype `T` behaves like `T<?,...,?>`, right?

Comment: How can you not care?  Why does A have a type parameter at all if you don't care about it when you override its methods?

Comment: So there are two layers: A and B is the type-safe part, where the compiler will give you errors, if you pass the wrong parameter for example. But there are many "unsafe" operations (where I just need to know its a C/D - or any A/B), that I don't want to expose in the type-safe layer.